# InnoDB Unique Constraints Slowing down inserts

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, innodb, unique-constraint

Hey guys so I have been wrestling with a problem in my Innodb. The database I am designing is binning built to house all domains listed under the .com and .net. I am reading these from a file and then input them into a data base each week. As you can guess there will be a lot of records. I have calculated close to 106 million .coms and 14 million .net (estimated) now in order to prevent duplicate records for domains I put a unique constraint on the domain name column and a second TLDid. When ever I do a update each week the inserts take 5-6 days. On the initial build with no data I got regular insert speeds until I started the inserts at 25 million and then it really started slowing.

I changed my innodb_buffer_pool_size=6000M with out much change. I was able to do inserts up to 45 million before it started to slow at around 3 hours.

I have read a lot of performance articles and changed more settings:

innodb_thread_concurrency=18

innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

innodb_file_per_table = 1

innodb_read_io_threads=3000 (Defaults to 64)

innodb_write_io_threads=7000 (Defaults to 64)

innodb_io_capacity=10000

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

I still am getting slow inserts:

Here is what the table looks like:

```
    -- Dumping structure for table domains.domains
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains` (
      `DomainID` bigint(19) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `DomainName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `TLDid` int(5) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
      `FirstSeen` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `LastUpdated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`DomainID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE DOMAIN INDEX` (`TLDid`,`DomainName`),
      KEY `TIMESTAMP INDEX` (`LastUpdated`,`FirstSeen`),
      KEY `TLD INDEX` (`TLDid`),
      KEY `DOMAIN NAME INDEX` (`DomainName`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

TLDid is either a 1 or a 2 but it will represent the extension of the domain for example "Test.com" will be stored as DomainName: Test TLDid 1. "Test.net" will be stored as DomainName: Test TLDid: 2.

My question is how can I optimize this table with 130 million plus records with 2 unique constraints that need to be check before inserts so that it doesn't slow down the table to take 14 days to update new and current records?

Thanks Guys

Comment: You've got a duplicate index - `TLD INDEX` is not necessary, since the field's already indexed by the `unique domain index` as the first field of that key. For bulk inserts of the size you're talking about, it might be quicker to disable indexes, do the inserts (dupes and all), re-enable indexes, then clean up the dupes afterwards.

Comment: The `TLDid` column would probably be better as `ENUM('.com','.net')`.  That way, you can address it as you are now as an integer, but MySQL "knows" what they mean so you more easily do concatenation to get the full name.  It would also only use 1 byte per row instead of your current `INT` column that uses 4 bytes per row.

Comment: Another thing: have you checked how much of the InnoDB buffer is used while the query is running?  My guess is that the buffer is overflowing and constantly having to be shuffled between memory and the disk.  If that is the case, that would cause severe performance problems like you're having.

Comment: Marc, I didn't knw you could do that. Thanks for the idea. Thanks nugget ill add that too. I believe you are right. When preforming the insert mysql loads all the unique constraints and checks them before the insert. So once you hit a point memory won't be able to hold all the unique constraints and it slows down tremendously.

Comment: @G-Nugget Using an `ENUM` for `TLDid` is likely a very bad idea. You'd be better to store them normalized in a table and referenced by ID. If you use an `ENUM` you'll have to `ALTER` the table for every additional TLD, which will be very expensive.

Comment: @jeremycole If new TLDs are needed, you are right, a normalized table would be better, but from the question, it sounds like there are only `.net` and `.com`.  If that is and will continue to be the case, `ENUM` would be better since all of the data is in one table and in a more precise format.

Comment: @G-Nugget I don't really agree with that. There is fundamentally very little difference between storing it normalized or denormalized as long as equivalent data types are chosen (e.g. `TINYINT` rather than `INT`). The performance will be the same, the queries will not be much different, but the list will be much more extensible.

Comment: @G-Nugget For lists which could not possibly contain additional values (e.g. true/false) I could be convinced that ENUM is a better choice for its inherent labeling of each value. Where the set of values is obviously incomplete, such as with the TLD example above, this is a dangerous assumption.